# Cоздать одновременно две и более строк в таблице

Tags: mysql, laravel

Как создать в одну таблицу сразу несколько строк, например:
id product_id order_id

```
@foreach($products as $product => $value)
 <tr><td>{{$value->name}}</td><td>{{$value->price}}</td></tr>
 <input type="text" name="id" hidden value="{{$value->id}}">
@endforeach
```

Есть скрытый инпут из которого я получаю айди товара.
Из за того что их может быть несколько, надо добавить их сразу.

Comment: В Mysql будет так: INSERT INTO table (id, product_id, order_id) VALUES(\* все три значения через запятую*\),(\* другие три значения через запятую*\) - и так сколько нужно строк

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#inserts

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в контроллере сделать это следующим образом:

```
$products = [
    ['product_id'=>'1', 'order_id'=> 30, 'count' => 1],
    ['product_id'=>'2', 'order_id'=> 30, 'count' => 2],
    //...
];

DB::table('order_product')->insert($data);
```